# Datatable - search multiple values with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am using Jquery datatable in my application. My table contains the following columns:

> `1.Name 2.Position 3.Office 4.Age 5.Date and 6.Salary`

In that, I am dynamically constructing a multi select filter options for 'Office' column from the table response. I have tried my example in the following JSFiddle link.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/630/)

**HTML Code**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-3 hoverable">
      <div class="card-title">
           <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
             <div class="col s12 m4">
               <h5>Summary</h5>
             </div>
             <div class="col s12 m3 right-align">


     <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" multiple="true">Office:                </span>
               <select multiple="true" id="officeFltr">
               </select>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <div class="summTblDiv">
              <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Position</th>
                          <th>Office</th>
                          <th>Age</th>
                          <th>Start date</th>
                          <th>Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                          <td>System Architect</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2011/04/25</td>
                          <td>$320,800</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                          <td>Accountant</td>
                          <td>Tokyo (Japan)</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2011/07/25</td>
                          <td>$170,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>41</td>
                          <td>2012/10/13</td>
                          <td>$132,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                          <td>Development Lead</td>
                          <td>New York (US)</td>
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>2011/09/03</td>
                          <td>$345,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                          <td>New York (US)</td>
                          <td>21</td>
                          <td>2011/12/12</td>
                          <td>$106,450</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                          <td>Sidney (Australia)</td>
                          <td>23</td>
                          <td>2010/09/20</td>
                          <td>$85,600</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/10/09</td>
                          <td>$1,200,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                          <td>42</td>
                          <td>2010/12/22</td>
                          <td>$92,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                          <td>28</td>
                          <td>2010/11/14</td>
                          <td>$357,650</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>28</td>
                          <td>2011/06/07</td>
                          <td>$206,850</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Fiona Green</td>
                          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>48</td>
                          <td>2010/03/11</td>
                          <td>$850,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Shou Itou</td>
                          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                          <td>Tokyo (Japan)</td>
                          <td>20</td>
                          <td>2011/08/14</td>
                          <td>$163,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Michelle House</td>
                          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                          <td>Sidney (Australia)</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2011/06/02</td>
                          <td>$95,400</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Suki Burks</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>53</td>
                          <td>2009/10/22</td>
                          <td>$114,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                          <td>Technical Author</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>27</td>
                          <td>2011/05/07</td>
                          <td>$145,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                          <td>Team Leader</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>22</td>
                          <td>2008/10/26</td>
                          <td>$235,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                          <td>46</td>
                          <td>2011/03/09</td>
                          <td>$324,050</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Unity Butler</td>
                          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/12/09</td>
                          <td>$85,675</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                          <td>Office Manager</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>51</td>
                          <td>2008/12/16</td>
                          <td>$164,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                          <td>Secretary</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>41</td>
                          <td>2010/02/12</td>
                          <td>$109,850</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                          <td>Financial Controller</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>62</td>
                          <td>2009/02/14</td>
                          <td>$452,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                          <td>Office Manager</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2008/12/11</td>
                          <td>$136,200</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                          <td>Director</td>
                          <td>New York (US)</td>
                          <td>65</td>
                          <td>2008/09/26</td>
                          <td>$645,750</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                          <td>64</td>
                          <td>2011/02/03</td>
                          <td>$234,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>38</td>
                          <td>2011/05/03</td>
                          <td>$163,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>Tokyo (Japan)</td>
                          <td>37</td>
                          <td>2009/08/19</td>
                          <td>$139,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Thor Walton</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>New York (US)</td>
                          <td>61</td>
                          <td>2013/08/11</td>
                          <td>$98,540</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                          <td>Support Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2009/07/07</td>
                          <td>$87,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                          <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                          <td>64</td>
                          <td>2012/04/09</td>
                          <td>$138,575</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>New York (US)</td>
                          <td>63</td>
                          <td>2010/01/04</td>
                          <td>$125,250</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                          <td>Software Engineer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>56</td>
                          <td>2012/06/01</td>
                          <td>$115,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                          <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                          <td>43</td>
                          <td>2013/02/01</td>
                          <td>$75,650</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                          <td>Regional Director</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>47</td>
                          <td>2011/03/21</td>
                          <td>$356,250</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Lael Greer</td>
                          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                          <td>London (England)</td>
                          <td>21</td>
                          <td>2009/02/27</td>
                          <td>$103,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                          <td>Developer</td>
                          <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                          <td>30</td>
                          <td>2010/07/14</td>
                          <td>$86,500</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                          <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                          <td>29</td>
                          <td>2011/06/27</td>
                          <td>$183,000</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>Donna Snider</td>
                          <td>Customer Support</td>
                          <td>New York (US)</td>
                          <td>27</td>
                          <td>2011/01/25</td>
                          <td>$112,000</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code**:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
       dom: 'lrtip',
        initComplete: function () {
          this.api().columns([2]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            console.log(column);
            var select = $("#officeFltr"); 
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
              select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
          } );

          $("#officeFltr").material_select();
       }
    });

    $('#officeFltr').on('change', function(){
        var search = [];

      $.each($('#officeFltr option:selected'), function(){
            search.push($(this).val());
      });

      search = search.join('|');
      table.column(2).search(search, true, false).draw();  
    });

});
```

But this filter function is not working since it contains special character brackets '(' & ')' in the option.

I tried the below motioned line also  to disable regex. But this is working fine only for single option and not for multiple options.

```
table.column(2).search(search, false, false).draw();
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because of parenthesis `()`

In order to work properly you have to add backslashes `\`

```
var escape_parenthesis = new RegExp( '(\\' + [ '(', ')'].join('|\\') + ')', 'g' );        
search = search.replace( escape_parenthesis, '\\$1' );
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o8wzr7y/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply the [Datatble escepe Regex util](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex()) function `$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex()` for each select value :

```
var val;
$.each($('#officeFltr option:selected'), function(){
   val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
   search.push(val);
});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmoos6tu/649/)

Snippet below :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'lrtip',
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns([2]).every(function() {
        var column = this;
        console.log(column);
        var select = $("#officeFltr");
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
        });
      });

      $("#officeFltr").material_select();
    }
  });

  $('#officeFltr').on('change', function() {
    var search = [];
    var val;
    $.each($('#officeFltr option:selected'), function() {
      val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
      search.push(val);
    });

    search = search.join('|');

    table.column(2).search(search, true, false).draw();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <div class="card z-depth-3 hoverable">
      <div class="card-title">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
          <div class="col s12 m4">
            <h5>Summary</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m3 right-align">
            <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:500;" multiple="true">Office:                </span>
            <select multiple="true" id="officeFltr">
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <div class="summTblDiv">
          <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo (Japan)</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York (US)</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York (US)</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney (Australia)</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo (Japan)</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney (Australia)</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York (US)</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo (Japan)</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York (US)</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York (US)</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh (Scotland)</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London (England)</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco (US)</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore (Singapore)</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York (US)</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```